# How to check a radio have onclick with caperjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, casperjs

This is my code:

Full code here: http://notepad.cc/casperjsstack1

```js
this.thenOpen('https://www.1800flowers.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/FDDeliveryOptionsDisplayCmd', function() {
  this.waitForSelector('#BP-DeliveryCardMess_1', function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
      var el = $('#giftMessages.noCard');
      el.onclick();
    });
  });
});
```

Look at the picture:  I want check No Gift Message

I try so much method but all false

Code HTML page here: http://notepad.cc/casperjsstack1_html

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [click()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/1.1-beta2/modules/casper.html#click)?

```
this.thenOpen('https://www.1800flowers.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/FDDeliveryOptionsDisplayCmd', function() {
    this.waitForSelector('#BP-DeliveryCardMess_1', function() {
        this.evaluate(function() {
            this.click('#giftMessages.noCard'); // Click the radio button.
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//jQuery version using evaluation page context
this.thenOpen('https://www.1800flowers.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/FDDeliveryOptionsDisplayCmd', function() {
    this.waitForSelector('#BP-DeliveryCardMess_1', function() {
        this.evaluate(function() {
            $("#giftMessages.noCard").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
        });
    });
});

//Casper version using click
this.thenOpen('https://www.1800flowers.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/FDDeliveryOptionsDisplayCmd', function() {
    this.waitForSelector('#BP-DeliveryCardMess_1', function() {
        this.click("#giftMessages.noCard");
    });
});
```